# Zookeeper change the default quorum and the leader election ports

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am looking at the documentation for setting up a cluster of zookeeper instances, one of the options(albeit its not redundant) is to set up multiple zookeeper instances on a single machine .

If I were to set up multiple instances on a single machine then I need to change the default quorum and the leader election ports from 2888 & 3888 to something else , how can I change the default port? There does not seem to be any documented way of doing so .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how to setup a cluster here:
- http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.7/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup

Which means you can change the ports for individual nodes in the cluster:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

Comment: I have seen this , this is insufficient information , if I were to change the ports from 2888:3888 to 2889:3889 for server.2 how would I do that  ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean, but how about something like this:

`server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2889:3889
server.3=zoo3:2890:3890`

Comment: yes, you are right , I did not realize that the port binding happens at run time and not at the start up time , so yes this is the way to have custom non default ports.